# Mostra tipo de dato con Panda en vsc

Tags: python, vscode, anaconda, conda

Tengo que hacer los dos siguientes ejercicios, el primero lo hago sin problema pero en el segundo no consigo mostrar el tipo de dato de la columna en cuestión, estoy usando vsc con entorno python 3.9.5 64-bit porque si uso entorno conda me lanza un error, alguna idea?

**Reading an Excel file**

**1.** Start by reading the excel file USCompanies.xlsx you are provided with in the course materials. This file contains information on prices and shares outstanding by US companies at the end of June 2018. Store the result of reading the excel file on a variable named usdata. Remember to place the .xlsx file in the same directory where your notebook is saved/created.

Note: you might want to take a look at Pandas' read_excel function.

```
import pandas as pd
​
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrador/Downloads/UScompanies.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

**Basic checks**

**2.** Check how Pandas read the data: Are column names included as values or headers? What fields (columns) and data (rows) are included in the file? Please, write code that could answer these questions.**

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrador/Downloads/UScompanies.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

df['Shares_Outstanding'].dtype
```

Cuando lo lanzo en consola no me muestra nada

Gracias por las ayudas de antemano!

​

Comment: No estás imprimiendo nada en consola. Debes utilizar `print(df['Shares_Outstanding'].dtype)`

Comment: Muchas gracias César, menudo error de novato! gracias por la ayuda, a veces lo más sencillo se nos escapa